# How can I silently upgrade macOS from intel (Rosetta) process?

Tags: macos, apple-m1, apple-silicon, rosetta, rosetta-2

I have an app with admin privileges running on M1 with Rosetta and I'm trying to silently upgrade the macOS.

for example, I tried to run an upgrade command from Terminal running on Intel (Rosetta)
[image]

The command I run is:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Monterey.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --agreetolicense –nointeraction --forcequitapps
```

and I got the following error:

> running in rosetta 2 is not supported

How can I make it work? or is there another way to silently install macOS patch from an Intel (Rosetta) process?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using arch, that way you can run from an intel process an apple command:

> sudo arch -arm64 /Applications/Install\ macOS
> Monterey.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --agreetolicense
> --forcequitapps --passprompt

Still the issue is that it can't be done silently since it needs password although I'm running with admin privileges